# Android Java TCP Client Server File Transfer

Tags: android, tcpclient

Edit*
I have successful on the client server. Now I am doing a file transferring between 2 emulators. The file did transfer between the emulators, but I notice that the file size received is not the same as the original file. For example, A.jpg size is 900KB, but the received file is less than 900KB. I checked the file transfer size, found that there were some data(byte) lost when transferring. How is this happening?

Here's the code:

Client (Send File)

```
File myFile = new File ("/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/A.jpg");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
int filesize = (int) myFile.length();

byte [] buffer  = new byte [filesize];
     int bytesRead =0;
     while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
     os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
//Log display exact the file size
     System.out.println("SO sendFile" + bytesRead);
     }
     os.flush();
     os.close();
     fis.close();
     Log.d("Client", "Client sent message");
     socket.close();
```

Server (Receive File)

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/B.jpg");
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();

byte[] aByte = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = is.read(aByte)) != -1) 
{
     bos.write(aByte, 0, bytesRead);
//Log display few parts the file size is less than 1024. I total up, the lost size caused the file received is incomplete
     System.out.println("SO sendFile" + bytesRead);
 }
clientSocket.close();
```

*Edit 2

While I surfed around google, I found that .read(buffer) does not guarantee read the full size(byte) of the file. Hence, the received file always lost some bytes (like space, empty character). To solve this, send the file size first to inform the receiver, then only start transfer the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NetworkOnMainThreadException`  occurs because you have to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

`NullPointerException` occurs because you are trying to use `PrintWriter` with the result of Sockets. As you have got nothing with Sockets you get this error.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I have done the client-server part, now i'm having problem on file transfer, as above stated, can you have a look on it? Thank you again.

Comment: sure let em look at it..:)

Comment: Is your image perfect after the file transfer or have any problems like lost few pixels?

Comment: the image's last few lines lost pixels

Comment: Any warnings at logcat atleast?

Comment: I surfed around google and discovered that .read(buffer) will always having problem when reading file size. I am able to solve by sending the file size first, then followed by transferring the file. By this way, the file transferring is working well.

Thanks for your kindness and helpful, JJPA :). Learned a lot from you.

Comment: I was actually on your programs. I was looking at the line `byte[] aByte = new byte[1024];` like anything, but I was doubtful. Anyways good to hear your problem is solved. +1 to you as you cleared your problems with google and leaving comments about how you solved it.

Comment: Before this, I was modified or removed the line too, but similar result returned.

Actually I'm doing a degree project for android, so is better to leave some comments, hopefully can be a helpful hint for other new learners like me.

Answer (score 0):

The [`NetworkOnMainThreadException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) tells you what you are doing wrong.

You need to put the network stuff into a separate Thread (or `AsyncTask` or similar).

Comment: Thanks for advice. I have done the client-server part, now i'm having problem on file transfer, as above stated, can you have a look on it? Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You can not call any server operation on Main Thread in Android.
In Android O.S 4.0 and above this will directly cause to **NetworkOnMainThreadException**. You have 2 choices :

1) Either to use **AsyncTask** to call your every server operation.

2) Or Use **User defined Thread** for any type of server operation.

I was also struggling with this Exception, only in OS version above 4.0 devices, So you can not ignore these small needs of Android.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I have done the client-server part, now i'm having problem on file transfer, as above stated, can you have a look on it? Thank you again.